# How to tell if (VB) code is running inside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using VB Express 2008. I know how to tell if code was built in debug more or release, but now I would like know how to tell if it is running in the Visual Studio IDE or not (so that I can add some debug MsgBox() and not worry about them showing if I ever accidentally ship a debug version).

Comment: Why don't you try Debug.Assert? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx

Comment: because it "Checks for a condition; if the condition is false, displays a message box that shows the call stack" and I don't want the call stack. Checking if running in the IDE is easy enough in Borland products, so I hoped it would be in VS 2008 too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached what you're looking for?

Comment: What happens when a developer tries debugging production code running on a customer? The code changes paths and thinks it is running from the VS IDE using your posted solution. Checking for an attached debugger ONLY tells the code if there is an active debugger attached, not if the code is in the IDE during development.

Comment: Do you have a better solution then, @StarPilot? Since this was the accepted answer it seems to have been the solution OP was looking for...

Comment: As long as the developer hasn't opted out of using vshost.exe, then the code can check to see if its executable name includes vshost. But it is possible to opt out of that, so it isn't 100% guaranteed accurate. The problem, as I commented above, is checking for a debug is a much bigger set of possibilities than just running in the IDE. Unfortunately, outside VSExtension code, there is no 100% way to tell if the IDE is hosting the running code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building for Test and Prod, consider using a preprocessor directive in your code.

```
#If DEBUG Then
    MsgBox("Foo")
#End If
```

This falls down, of course, if you ship a debug-built binary to a non-dev environment. I understand this is attacking the problem from another angle from where you asked the question (the IDE).

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the [IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) property of System.Diagnostics.Debugger

Comment: sorry, but @guy beat to to it by one minute (+1, though)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure you never show debug messages to users, you can use `Debug.Write()` and `Debug.WriteLine()`. These commands will output the text supplied to the debug output window. Note that you can attack a debug output window to a program running production code on a customer's machine without installing a development environment!

Testing for an attached debugger does not indicate that the debugger is also inside an IDE. It is quite common in many environments to attach debuggers to production code running on a customer system to identify what is going wrong on a particular customer's installation and usage. Testing for a debugger and then presuming you are in an IDE will foul out this usage of debuggers in a production environment.